# Ranking the countries with the most records of a certain type

Tags: r

I am looking at different species of Melaleuca (bottlebrushes) that occur in different countries and have different invasion statuses.

I have a csv file called "Glonaffinal2" that looks like this: [R script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vIKH.png)

But there are over 500 000 records.

I need to rank the countries (with the number); from the country with the most number of records, to the least number of records, for each invasive status (introduced, naturalized, invasive) separately.

Please can you help

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the code you tried and with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is the name of your dataset.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this solves the question's problem. Untested, since there are no data.

```
library(dplyr)

Glonaffinal2 %>%
  count(country, status) %>%
  mutate(rank = rank(-n)) %>%
  arrange(desc(rank), country)
```

Comment: Thank you! It ranked the countries, but not for the different statuses separately. But that is fine, I can edit it in excel. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: @MicheleterHuurne It ranks by country and status, but country comes first. To sse it, change the last intruction to `arrange(country, desc(rank))`.